# Raspberry pi bluetooth not detecting on React-Native based application. (Used react-native-ble-magaer)

Tags: android, react-native, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

I am trying to get the **Raspberry pi Bluetooth** signal or the peripheral device characteristic on my **React-Native** application. I am using [`react-native-ble-manager`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-manager) to scan and detect the peripheral devices. So far I got most of the devices like ***TV***, ***Smart-Bands*** etc. But not getting the raspberry signal.

I did confirm if the network is enabled and visible to my mobile from the device(Mobile) **Bluetooth Manager**. Everything seems to be fine. I am using a ***realme XT*** handset for this application. I have also checked on different handsets and even those had the same problem. So, I think it's the problem of the component and not the mobile.

If there is a different approach with different package, even that approach is fine for me.
Can someone help me on this!!.

Thank You!!

Comment: You want to find the Raspberry Pi using Bluetooth Low Energy. What did you do on the Raspberry Pi to start a BLE GATT Server? If the Raspberry Pi does not advertise a BLE service you wont find it searching for BLE peripherals

Comment: Thank you!! 
Got the solution!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments Raspberry Pi doesn't have a ***BLE*** service as default or maybe my code to enable the Bluetooth service doesn't have ***BLE***.

My solution for this was using a different package. I replaced `react-native-ble-manager` to [`react-native-bluetooth-serial-next`](https://github.com/nuttawutmalee/react-native-bluetooth-serial-next) and walaaa!!.

Everything is working fine!!

Comment: Now you are using Bluetooth classic and not Bluetooth Low Energy. But this might be what you wanted in the first place anyway

Comment: is this solution working with `iOS` and `RPI` connectivity and `read/write` data from `RPI`